# how can I get text of link button in my rad grid by jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a grid that contains link-button for code column .The user can check each checkbox and when user clicked on the top button of my page  all of code that user checked will be displayed in a text-box in another page. It means : (the user can select multiple row by checked check-box and pass all code that user select by jQuery function to  text-box in another page), but my problem is I cant access and get text of the code. I used CSS and it works. It become yellow, but I can't  access text when i run it. the alert statement represent me this text instead of code:

```
function (e){
    return b.access(this,function(e){
        return e===t?b.text(this):this.empty().append(
                         (this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument || o).createTextNode(e))
    },null,e,arguments.length)
}
```

How can I fix this problem? if anybody knows please help me to fix it, thanks.

```
function selectcheckCheckBoxes() {
    alert("1234 ");
    var gridClientID = $("#gvwHuman");
    jQuery.each($("#gvwHuman input:checkbox"), function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parent().next().css('background-color', 'green');

            var a = $(this).parent().next().css('background-color', 'red'); ;
            var j = $(a).find(".link").css('background-color', 'yellow'); ;
            var j2 = $(j).text;
            alert(j2);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var j2 = $(a).find(".link").text();
```

if it doesn't work, could you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

The below code won't give the text of the link.its wrong syntax.

```
  var j2 = $(j).text;
```

So change this as

```
var j2 = $(a).find(".link").text();
```

Comment: @sara Sodagari sorry for repeating the same answer.i didnt see that.